# npm error peer invalid webpack-dev-server@2.10.0 wants webpack@^2.2.0 ||

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-install

I have installed the dependencies via npm below is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "springbootreactjs2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Spring boot with reactjs",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "rest": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "7.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0"
  }
}
```

Whenever i want to install a dependency it keeps throwing the below error

```
npm WARN package.json springbootreactjs2@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json springbootreactjs2@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react@16.0.0" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package webpack@3.10.0 does not satisfy its siblings' p
eerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer babel-loader@6.4.1 wants webpack@1 || 2 || ^2.1.0-beta
 || ^2.2.0-rc
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer webpack-dev-server@2.10.0 wants webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0
.0

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Below is the install command i am running

```
npm install --save reactstrap@next react react-dom
```

Originally the webpack version was 3.10.0 i manually modified the webpack version to 2.2.0 but still for some reasons is still picking version 3.10.0.

Not sure what's wrong here

Comment: Can you share more steps? I can try it my laptop.

Comment: try deleting the package-lock.json file and run the install command

Comment: @Syed i don't see any such file, can you please tell me where should i look for this file ?

Comment: check in your root folder of your project. you will find it in the same location as your `package.json` file

Comment: double checked it its not there

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove any dependencies from your package.json file that you don't have installed locally and try again
2. Update your npm using `npm install -g npm@latest`.
   Install the missing dependencies using `npm install
   <dependency_name>` and run your command again.

If that doesn't work, read on:

I was facing the same issue. Although I was able to install webpack using npm, I couldn't install webpack-cli. So I:

1. 1) Updated npm version to the latest.
2. Installed yarn (using yum
   or apt-get, etc.).
3. Installed all the dependencies(including
   webpack-cli) using yarn

This solved my problem.